# UIButton will not perform CATransform3DMakeScale

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to perform a `CATransform3DMakeScale` on a `UIButton's` layer, but the scale transform doesn't seem to be working. The position animation works, but the scale does not

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationOutDuration delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.alpha = 0.0f;
                     CGPoint position = self.layer.position;
                     position.y += self.bounds.size.height*animationTranslationPercentage;
                     self.layer.position = position;
                     self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(animateOutEndScale, animateOutEndScale, 1.0f);

                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
```

Comment: What's the value of your animateOutEndScale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code like yours, with some parameter replaced. It works fine.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 50.0f)];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[button setTitle:@"lololo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         button.alpha = 0.0f;
                         CGPoint position = button.layer.position;
                         position.y += button.bounds.size.height*2.0;
                         button.layer.position = position;
                         button.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.0f);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
});
```

The button moves down, scales, and fades.

So my guess is your `animateOutEndScale` may be 1.0f

Comment: so the scale was 0.2f, but I realized that the super class also had a CATransform3DMakeScale of .95f. Silly mistake and it works!